# Made a change to 'Path length on Finder Tabs' - I need to change it back to default

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, catalina

I read an article that led me to change the way the file pathway shows up on tabs in Finder. So instead of a Tab just reading "/Downloads", it starts with /Users/MyName/Downloads. This is NOT what I wanted to do, and I don't know how to change it back. The filenames are so long that if I have 6 or more tabs going across, then file paths are truncated so they all look like they read the same thing, and I have to click on each tab to see what it is. This is a big time waster when you have to do it several times a day.

[I copied and pasted some text in to the terminal application to change Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74965/new-to-os-x-how-do-i-navigate-through-finder). I'm running MacOS Catalina 10.15.6

Can anyone tell me how to change back Finder to default?

Comment: What article, where? Add that link to your question. If we don't know exactly what you did we can't help you undo it.

Comment: I don't know where the article is anymore. I don't even remember who wrote it or what blog it was on etc. That's why I asked here to see if anyone had experience in making this change. I think I have my answer below from Ted Wrigley's response.

Answer (score 2):

The unix command you used in terminal was the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool YES
```

This adds a key to the Finder user defaults — `_FXShowPosixPathInTitle` — and sets it to true, which enables showing the full posix path of the file in the title bar. To turn that feature off and return to the original behavior, delete the key:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle
```

For more information about using the defaults utility, see its [man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/defaults/). Once you delete the entry, it’s best to log out of your user from the Apple menu and then log back in to be sure the preference stuck.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a go. This has been driving me nuts for months.

Comment: You are a genius!!! I can't thank you enough really. Omygoodness, you just saved me so many headaches. Have a beautiful, wonderful, week ahead of you, my friend. :-)

Comment: FYI - I upvoted your answer but apparently my votes won't publicly show because I'm new and do not have a reputation. Sorry. It was recorded though! So that's good news.

Comment: @BartoliniDesignCo.: No worries... 

Comment: Thanks for being generous in thanks here @BartoliniDesignCo. Since no one voted up your question your votes will be recorded, but not grant a reputation bump. Soon, I’m sure you can vote up good specific answers.

Comment: For this change to become visible, you'll have to relaunch the Finder, which you can do by logging out/in (as above), or by using "Force Quit Applications".